# c++ shared object dependencies

Tags: c++, ldd

after .so compilation the ldd command returns 3 unknown dependencies.

    `libboost_regex-gcc41-mt-1_35.so.1.35.0 => not found
    libsqlapi.so => not found
    libsqlapiu.so => not found`

Although they are specified in makefile and present at machine (RH 64 bit).
LD_LIBRARY_PATH is not set (need a solution without altering it)

    `libMakeMeHappy_so_LDADD = -L/usr/local/lib64/ -lboost_regex-gcc41-mt -lsqlapi -lsqlapiu`

Any comment why and how to prevent it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you need to figure out where those missing libraries reside on your machine. They might be in `/usr/local/lib64/`

Then you can chose one of these 3 options:

1. Set the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` env variable to point to `/usr/local/lib64/`
2. Update the global library path:

   - Add `/usr/local/lib64/` to `/etc/ld.so.conf`
   - Run `ldconfig`
3. Add `/usr/local/lib64/` as a library path to your shared library (or to the executables using your library)

   - Add the linker flag `-Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib64/` when linking
     the the shared library or executable.